# use python for restful server under gwan

Tags: python, servlets, g-wan

How to use python within g-wan? Provide a main method as in the c 'servlet'

Further is it possible to run python bottle or use its nice PUT GET POST handler syntax within said python
Aka

```
 @get(/classes/<classname>/<guid>
 def function(classname = none,guid = none)


 @put(/classes/<classname>/<guid>
 def function(classname = none,guid = none)
```

Yes. I'd prefer to use c but need to use a api written in the usual suspects php,node,python and c#

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> How to use **Python** scripts with g-wan?

There's a Python example on the [developer page](http://gwan.ch/developers#tab8) of the G-WAN web site, also available [here](http://gwan.ch/source/hello.py) and in the G-WAN download archive.

Recently, we have added the `X_HTTP_HEADERS` environment variable for the scripts like `Python` which use the CGI interface.

For `PHP`, the support of `$_GET`, `$_POST`, and `$_COOKIE` variables has also been added.

If you need assistance or new features for Python then contact us at the G-WAN web site. With the help of Python experts, we could load the language runtime from G-WAN (like this was done for C/C++, C#, Objective-C, Java, and Scala).

This is leading to a better ingration (as variables and API calls can be shared with G-WAN) and more speed.

Comment: I missed the tab for each language. Thx. How would U suggest handling each verb, post, put ,etc. Pass of to a diff script AFTER determining the verb as in url writing example found under Conn handlers here http://gwan.com/developers

Comment: I see that c# is acceptably fast on gwan. given Linux only gwan plus above comments re 'like this was done for c/c++, c# ... what r the starting pts for c# on gwan. thnk u

Comment: You can do an URL rewrite to redirect each GET/PUT method to a different script but a single script can also find the HTTP method and act accordingly, see the http://gwan.ch/source/hello.py example.

Comment: To install and configure the 'Mono C#' runtime under Linux see: http://gwan.ch/faq#languages (and the bash script mentionned in the green array on the left).